# Add custom metadata and password protect PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

i try to write a custom metadata to a pdf and password protect the pdf with the following code -
(you can try this with every pdf-file)

```
import os, sys
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter

if __name__ == '__main__':
  path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) 
  fnTemplate = os.path.join(path, "template.pdf")
  propName = "Some Name"
  propValue = f"Some Value"
  wPW = "pw1"

  # Write custom metadata
  with open(fnTemplate, "rb") as file:
    pdf_reader = PdfReader(file)
    pdf_writer = PdfWriter()
    [pdf_writer.add_page(page) for page in pdf_reader.pages]
    pdf_writer.add_metadata(
      {
        f"/{propName}": propValue,
        **pdf_reader.metadata,
      }
    )
    with open("workPDF1.pdf", "wb") as outFile:
      pdf_writer.write(outFile)    

  # Password protect pdf
  reader = PdfReader("workPDF1.pdf")
  writer = PdfWriter()
  writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader)
  writer.encrypt(wPW)
  with open("finalPDF.pdf", "wb") as out_file:
    writer.write(out_file)
```

My problem now is, that in the "finalPDF.pdf" the pdf is only password-protected but the custom metadata entry is gone. When i check the workfile "workPDF1.pdf" from the previous step the custom metadata is there

[image]

How can i set the custom metadata and password-protect the pdf-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do it using PyMuPDF.

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

propName = "valid-name"  # must be a valid PDF name: no spaces!
propValue = "Some value"
my_pass = "pw1"  # password (user & owner)
doc = fitz.open("input.pdf")

what, value = doc.xref_get_key(-1, "Info")  # /Info key in the trailer
if what != "xref":
    raise ValueError("PDF has no metadata")

info = int(value.replace("0 R", ""))  # extract the metadata xref

# print current content
print("\nOld metadata:")
for key in doc.xref_get_keys(info):
    print(key, "=", doc.xref_get_key(info, key)[1])

# add some private information
doc.xref_set_key(info, propName, fitz.get_pdf_str(propValue))

# show result:
print("\nNew metadata:")
for key in doc.xref_get_keys(info):
    print(key, "=", doc.xref_get_key(info, key)[1])

doc.ez_save(
    "protected.pdf",
    user_pw=my_pass,
    owner_pw=my_pass,
    encryption=fitz.PDF_ENCRYPT_AES_256,
)
```

Prints this output:

```
Old metadata:
Producer = mPDF 8.0.0
CreationDate = 20190707192125+00'00'
ModDate = 20190707192125+00'00'

New metadata:
Producer = mPDF 8.0.0
CreationDate = 20190707192125+00'00'
ModDate = 20190707192125+00'00'
valid-name = Some value
```

Confirm result by looking at produced file "protected.pdf":

```py
In [2]: doc = fitz.open("protected.pdf")
In [4]: doc.authenticate("pw1")
Out[4]: 6
In [5]: for key in doc.xref_get_keys(info):
   ...:     print(key, "=", doc.xref_get_key(info, key)[1])
   ...:
Producer = mPDF 8.0.0
CreationDate = 20190707192125+00'00'
ModDate = 20190707192125+00'00'
valid-name = Some value
```